# How Can I Select a Column for Every Third Row in an Excel Table?

Tags: excel, select, multiple-columns

I am trying to do this to move these columns over so they can be a part of the same rows above them.
Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Is there any way to do this without selecting them one by one while holding the `CTRL` key?

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One time activity, or is this something that would need to happen repeatedly?

Comment: @Kermit Can you please go more in depth? My input format would be selecting columns like the ones shown in the image, but not selecting them one by one using the mouse/`CTRL` key (That is what I have done in the image). Ken, it would be most likely repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down and dirty solution,  Assuming top left is top of sheet, cell A1.

Cell C1:

```
=A2
```

Cell D1

```
=B2
```

Cell E1

```
=MOD(ROW(A1),3)=1
```

Copy to entire range

Copy and Paste Values only

Sort by Column E

Delete all "FALSE" rows

To make repeatable, record macro of you doing it once.  You should then be able to edit resulting macro to make it "generic".

**EDIT**

If the top left is not A1, you can modify the =MOD(ROW(A1),3)=2 or =0 to select the correct row.

Comment: Filtering would work if there is a header row, otherwise I believe row 1 would still show when filtering "FALSE"

Comment: @Ken I think I will just use an auto clicker application. I can't seem to figure out your code, but I do see where you are coming from. Therefore, I will give you best answer. Thank you for the help, Ken.

Comment: What problems were you having?  The concept is that in column C I'm picking up the next rows column A value.  In Column D I'm picking up the next rows Column B value.  I use the MOD formula to figure out if it's a row to keep, or not.  Range value the entries and eliminate the "false" rows.